# Woocommerce Add to cart product is empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing an eCommerce solution using Gravity Forms and Woocommerce. Now the problem is that on my local host everything is working fine.

As soon as I transfer the website to live server the cart page does not show on product add.

You can recreate the problem by visiting this url cosmosample.com/phoking4/

And click on menu tab.

As you can see the cart page should appear after clicking on add to cart but that does not happen. What could be the possible cause of this kind of behavior.

I would also like to add that add_to_cart is working as when I see the cart directly, it sometimes shows me all the times, I have added the product, so there is some problem with the way the cart is being displayed.

Comment: you have a javascript error.. check your console... fix it, and your add to cart will work..

Comment: [visit this link](http://cosmosample.com/phoking4/menu/?add-to-cart=272), and check your cart after..

Comment: Please let me know, how can I check from console. And how can I easily to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Manoj please explain briefly your question but as per my understand i thought you want redirect to cart page when some one click on the add to cart button.  For this you should have to login with admin 
Go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display 
then click on the "Redirect to the cart page after successful addition" checkbox and Save Changes.

Comment: No, please only add to cart item is not add on this live server. but it's properly working on localhost.

Comment: please see screenshot.
http://screencast.com/t/hQdXTQ6ahKvz
please give me the solution.